# Using a HashMap without Sync in an async fn

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I have a repository trait with `get` and `set` methods, and I am trying create an implementation of this trait that wraps around another implementation of this trait. I am using `async` so everything needs to be `Send`, but I do not care for `Sync`. It's fine if this code only works on a single thread.

However, in my wrapper I keep getting errors around the `HashMap` used in the wrapper's `get` not being `Sync`. I'm not sure why this is an issue though. I guess technically `get` could be called in parallel, but this access would also be immutable so it wouldn't matter? And besides, I want any concurrency to be handled at a higher level, so the error should not happen here but at the place where this function would be called in parallel.

I was able to get it to work by putting the `HashMap` in a `Mutex`, but that is something I very much would like to avoid.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bfc88b5d657d162bf034f3d11a1f7d7)

```rust
use std::{marker::PhantomData, collections::HashMap};
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct IVec3 {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
    pub z: i32
}

trait VoxelComponent : Copy + Send {}
enum VoxelRepositoryError{}

#[async_trait]
trait VoxelRepository<T: VoxelComponent> : Send {
    async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<T>, VoxelRepositoryError>;
    async fn set(&mut self, position: IVec3, component: Option<T>) -> Result<(), VoxelRepositoryError>;
}

struct DiffVoxelRepository<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> {
    source_repository: R,
    cache: HashMap<IVec3, C>,
    _component: PhantomData<fn() -> C>
}

impl<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
    fn new(repository: R) -> DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
        DiffVoxelRepository {
            source_repository: repository,
            cache: HashMap::new(),
            _component: PhantomData
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> VoxelRepository<C> for DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
    
    async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
        match self.cache.get(&position) {
            Some(value) =>  Ok(Some(*value)),
            None => self.source_repository.get(position).await
        }
    }

    async fn set(&mut self, position: IVec3, component: Option<C>) -> Result<(), VoxelRepositoryError>{
        match component {
            Some(c) => self.cache.insert(position, c),
            None => self.cache.remove(&position)
        };

        self.source_repository.set(position, component).await
    }
}
```

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:39:85
   |
39 |       async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
   |  _____________________________________________________________________________________^
40 | |         match self.cache.get(&position) {
41 | |             Some(value) =>  Ok(Some(*value)),
42 | |             None => self.source_repository.get(position).await
43 | |         }
44 | |     }
   | |_____^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
note: captured value is not `Send` because `&` references cannot be sent unless their referent is `Sync`
  --> src/lib.rs:39:19
   |
39 |     async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
   |                   ^^^^ has type `&DiffVoxelRepository<R, C>` which is not `Send`, because `DiffVoxelRepository<R, C>` is not `Sync`
   = note: required for the cast from `[async block@src/lib.rs:39:85: 44:6]` to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError>> + Send`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
37 | impl<R: VoxelRepository<C> + std::marker::Sync, C: VoxelComponent> VoxelRepository<C> for DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
   |                            +++++++++++++++++++

error[E0277]: `C` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:39:85
   |
39 |       async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
   |  _____________________________________________________________________________________^
40 | |         match self.cache.get(&position) {
41 | |             Some(value) =>  Ok(Some(*value)),
42 | |             None => self.source_repository.get(position).await
43 | |         }
44 | |     }
   | |_____^ `C` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = note: required because it appears within the type `(IVec3, C)`
   = note: required for `hashbrown::raw::RawTable<(IVec3, C)>` to implement `Sync`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `HashMap<IVec3, C, RandomState>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `HashMap<IVec3, C>`
note: required because it appears within the type `DiffVoxelRepository<R, C>`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:8
   |
20 | struct DiffVoxelRepository<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> {
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: required for `&DiffVoxelRepository<R, C>` to implement `Send`
note: required because it's used within this `async` block
  --> src/lib.rs:39:85
   |
39 |       async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
   |  _____________________________________________________________________________________^
40 | |         match self.cache.get(&position) {
41 | |             Some(value) =>  Ok(Some(*value)),
42 | |             None => self.source_repository.get(position).await
43 | |         }
44 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: required for the cast from `[async block@src/lib.rs:39:85: 44:6]` to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError>> + Send`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
37 | impl<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent + std::marker::Sync> VoxelRepository<C> for DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
   |
```

Comment: But the ability to share a `&T` between threads is precisely what `T: Sync` means. Imagine that `T` had some interior mutability (`RefCell` or `Rc`), then you share a `&T` between threads and... race condition! If you know that will just not happen you have to tell to the compiler with `T: Sync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using `async` so everything needs to be `Send`, but I do not care for `Sync`. It's fine if this code only works on a single thread.

Using `async` does not require you to use `Send` — only multi-threaded async executors require that. However, the `async_trait` library assumes by default that you *do* want `Send` on all the futures. You can [ask it not to](https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/async_trait/#non-threadsafe-futures) with `#[async_trait(?Send)]`.

The following version of your program compiles, with these changes:

- Removed all the `Send` bounds.
- Replaced `#[async_trait]` with `#[async_trait(?Send)]`.
- Added `derive(Clone, Copy)` to `IVec3`. (This is an unrelated problem revealed after the others were fixed.)

If you do, instead, want to keep the `Send` bounds, then you will indeed need to add `Sync` bounds to types that you are operating on via `&` reference from `Send` futures, because in general, `&T: Send` only when `T: Sync`, so using an `&T` reference from a `Send` future requires that `T` implement `Sync`. `Send` and `Sync` are closely related and you generally can't use `Send` without *sometimes* using `Sync`.

```rust
use std::{marker::PhantomData, collections::HashMap};
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct IVec3 {
    pub x: i32,
    pub y: i32,
    pub z: i32
}

trait VoxelComponent : Copy {}
enum VoxelRepositoryError{}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
trait VoxelRepository<T: VoxelComponent> {
    async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<T>, VoxelRepositoryError>;
    async fn set(&mut self, position: IVec3, component: Option<T>) -> Result<(), VoxelRepositoryError>;
}

struct DiffVoxelRepository<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> {
    source_repository: R,
    cache: HashMap<IVec3, C>,
    _component: PhantomData<fn() -> C>
}

impl<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
    fn new(repository: R) -> DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
        DiffVoxelRepository {
            source_repository: repository,
            cache: HashMap::new(),
            _component: PhantomData
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait(?Send)]
impl<R: VoxelRepository<C>, C: VoxelComponent> VoxelRepository<C> for DiffVoxelRepository<R, C> {
    
    async fn get(&self, position: IVec3) -> Result<Option<C>, VoxelRepositoryError> {
        match self.cache.get(&position) {
            Some(value) =>  Ok(Some(*value)),
            None => self.source_repository.get(position).await
        }
    }

    async fn set(&mut self, position: IVec3, component: Option<C>) -> Result<(), VoxelRepositoryError>{
        match component {
            Some(c) => self.cache.insert(position, c),
            None => self.cache.remove(&position)
        };
    
       self.source_repository.set(position, component).await
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you write `#[async_trait(?Send)]` ? with an extra argument ? According to its sources it does not use this https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/src/async_trait/lib.rs.html#341

Comment: @unegare I followed the documentation, and confirmed that it compiled. But also, in the code, you can see that `args` is passed to [`impl Parse for Args`](https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/src/async_trait/args.rs.html) which then looks for `?Send` or nothing.